# Generic class Implementation for a SpringData & QueryDSL Service

Tags: java, spring, generics, querydsl

I have a bunch of service classes that have repositories that extends JpaRepository and QueryDslPredicateExecutor.
The methods in the service classes are identical except for the entity that it processes. I am trying to create
a generic service class but I am getting a "Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pkg.BaseRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency".

Below are my classes:

```
//BaseRepository.java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {}

//RegionRepository.java
@Repository
public interface RegionRepository<Region> extends JpaRepository<Region, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Region> {}

//ProvinceRepository.java
@Repository
public interface ProvinceRepository<Province> extends JpaRepository<Province, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Province> {}
```

...
and many more XxxRepository interfaces

```
//AbstractBaseService.java
public abstract class AbstractBaseService<T>{
    @Autowired 
    private BaseRepository<T> repository;

    public void add(T entity) {
        System.out.println("Adding entity " + entity.getClass());
    }

    public T retrieve(Long id) {
        System.out.println("Retrieving region with dbId = " + id);
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
    ...
    //some other methods

}

//RegionService.java
@Service("regService")
public class RegionService extends AbstractBaseService<Region> {}

//ProvinceService.java
@Service("provService")
public class ProvinceService extends AbstractBaseService<Province> {}


@Controller
public class MyController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/application-context.xml");

        MyController controller = new MyController();
        controller.run(context);
    }

    public void run(ApplicationContext context) {       
        RegionService regService =  (RegionService)context.getBean("regService");
        Region reg = regService.retrieve(1L);
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="generics" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">      
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

application-context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dreamcorps.gen" />

    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:spring/db.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database"           value="${jpa.dbVendor}" />
                <property name="databasePlatform"   value="${jpa.dialect}"  />
                <property name="showSql"            value="${jpa.showSql}"  />  
                <property name="generateDdl"        value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="generics" />    
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- access -->
        <property name="driverClass"                value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"                    value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="user"                       value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password"                   value="${jdbc.password}"/>

        <!-- pool sizing -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize"            value="${c3p0.initialPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize"                value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize"                value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement"           value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}"/>
        <property name="maxStatements"              value="${c3p0.maxStatements}"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.dreamcorps.gen" />

</beans>
```

Below is the error log when MyController is run.

```
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:35 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.3.Final}
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:35 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:35 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:36 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:36 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
Dec 12, 2015 12:49:36 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.dreamcorps.sample.controller.MyController.main(MyController.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 28 more


Is there a way to make the AbstractBaseService work as I envision above so that I don't have to create the one Service class with the same implementation as AbstractBaseService for each of my entities (Region, Province, User, Vehicle.... etc)?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

```
//RegionRepository.java
@Repository
public interface RegionRepository<Region> extends JpaRepository<Region, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Region> {}
                                  ^^^^^^ Here you are actually making a new Type Variable, which is bounded to Object.
```

You are making new Type Variables, this actually hides the class name you are making the Repository for.

Comment: Ruben, thanks for your quick reply/comment. I am actually struggling with generics at this time. can u guide or give me additional suggestion as to what should be done either with the BaseRepository or the Region/Province repositories.

Comment: Only the `BaseRepository<T>` should have a type parameter, the `RegionRepository implements BaseRepository<Region>` should only fill in the blanks from the interface, not declare additional type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make my original post work. What were missing were the annotation @NoRepositoryBean on the BaseRepository.java interface and @Repository annotations on RegionRepository/ProvinceRepository interfaces as edited above.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the answer. Now we don't see the initial question with the problem anymore. Instead, keep the question as is and write the solution in the answer.